# subdivide_edges VS Loop cut in Python

Tags: python

Please explain why my attached code does not exshibit a cut line in the 3d Viewport on the top face of the cube. Also I'd appreciatre an explanation of the differeces between loopcut and subdivide_edges.

```py
import bpy, bmesh
    
def create_cube_foundation(cube_size=20, location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1)):
    # Create a cube
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=cube_size, location=location)
    cube = bpy.context.object
    
    # Set cube rotation and scale
    cube.rotation_euler = rotation
    cube.scale = scale
    
    # Ensure we're in object mode with the correct object active
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = cube
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    # Create a bmesh from the cube mesh
    mesh = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(cube.data)
    
    # Add a loop cut using bmesh operations
    ret = bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges(mesh, edges=mesh.edges, cuts=1, use_grid_fill=True)
    
    # Update the mesh with the new data
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(cube.data)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    
    # Rest of your code...

# Example usage:
create_cube_foundation()
```

Comment: Your code works fine. I verified by switching to *Edit Mode* after running it. I couldn't find a `bmesh.ops.loopcut()` operator. Is this a general question not specific to `bmesh`?

Comment: One possible reason why it doesn't work like you want it to, is that you asked chatGPT first. Normally when you (improperly) ask a human being, you will get a response, that it's not clear what you're asking, and if you can clarify. But ChatGPT will simply answer. Now you take this code and ask why it doesn't work without explaining what you're actually trying to do, and as Mr A points out, it works, and we simply don't have a way to figure out what you wanted to do instead of what you get.

Answer (score 0):

About the difference between 'Loop Cut' and 'Subdivide' :

In general terms - 'Loop Cut' is meant to subdivide faces, when 'Subdivide' is meant to subdivide edges.

In the second case if subdivided edges belong to the opposite sides of the face – this face also will be subdivided.

---

By the way, if you wanted to subdivide the top face solely – you can use the code I've wrote.

HERE:

```
import bpy, bmesh
  
    
def add_cube(size, location, rotation, scale):
##
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=size,location=location,
    
    rotation=rotation, scale=scale)   
    
    
    cube = bpy.context.object

    return cube
##


def subdivide(cube):
##    
    
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = cube
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')


    cube_bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(cube.data)
    
    top_z_coordinate = max([vert.co.z for vert in cube_bm.verts])
    
    top_edges = []


    for edge in cube_bm.edges:
    #    
        z0 = edge.verts[0].co.z
        
        z1 = edge.verts[1].co.z
        
        
        if z0 == z1 == top_z_coordinate:
        
            top_edges.append(edge)
    #


    edge_0 = top_edges[0]
    
    for edge in top_edges:
    #   
        v0 = edge.verts[0] 
        v1 = edge.verts[1]
        
        if(v0 not in edge_0.verts) and (v1 not in edge_0.verts):
           
            edge_1 = edge
            break
    #  


    subdivide = [edge_0,edge_1]
            
    bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges(cube_bm, edges=subdivide, cuts=1, use_grid_fill=True)
    

    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(cube.data)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
##    



cube = add_cube(size=20, location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))

subdivide(cube)
```

---

After executing my code you will get this result :

[image: code output]

---

P.S.

Sorry for some persons where down-voting  your question. I sincerely don't get it...